# How to show selected checkbox on next screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I am new to flutter. i have created checkbox but don't know how to show selected checkbox data on next screen. Here is my code:

```
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: (){},
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: HexColor('#09B9B6')),
                                ),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(HexColor('#F2FFFF'))
                          ),
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            title:  Text('Maid Service', style: new TextStyle(color: HexColor('#09B9B6'), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            subtitle: Text('35 Dollar / 1 Hour'),
                            value: this.valueFifth,
                            checkColor: HexColor("#F2FFFF"),
                            activeColor: HexColor("#09B9B6"),
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                this.valueFifth = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

> please help

Comment: pass the bool value to next screen, then show the status of check box based on the bool value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data from one screen to another and build next screen accordingly.

Here is an instruction about how to pass data https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments